# What is the best approach for validating a combination of values using ENUMS in Java?

Tags: java, validation, enums

I am validating the status of a record retrieved from the DB by defining an ENUM as below

```
public enum RecordStatusEnum {
    CREATED("CREATED"),
    INSERTED("INSERTED"),   
    FAILED("FAILED");

private String recordStatusValue;

    RecordStatusEnum (String status) {
        recordStatusValue= status;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return (this.equals(CREATED) || this.equals(INSERTED));
    }

}
```

The method isSuccess() is being used to check the status of the retrieved record ( column status from employee)

```
if (!(employee.getStatus().isSuccess())) {
            // return error
        }
```

As per the new requirement, there are a set of conditions introduced say A,B and C; and for them there is a column in the Employee table 'condition'.

So I need to retrieve the status as well as the condition and see if it belongs to a set which has the combination of both.

For eg : isSuccess() should check if in the following:

```
CREATED and A 
CREATED and B
INSERTED and C
```

This must be achieved such that it is easy for me to add a new combination say 'INSERTED and B' into the list easily.

What is the best approach for the above problem?

***Note** : in the actual business scenario there are a whole lot more statuses and checks (eg isFailed() canBeModified() etc) with many different combinations*

***And any method can be suggested even if it doesn't use ENUMS. I mentioned ENUMS, because I dont want to deviate much from the existing implementation***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities, but you could do like this (I removed the String status, which doesn't add any value since it's equal to the name of the enum):

```
public enum RecordStatusEnum {
    CREATED(Condition.A, Condition.B),
    INSERTED(Condition.C),   
    FAILED();

    private Set<Condition> successConditions;

    RecordStatusEnum(Condition... successConditions) {
        this.successConditions = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(successConditions));
    }

    public boolean isSuccess(Condition c) {
        return successConditions.contains(c);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Example with two sets of conditions:

```
public enum RecordStatusEnum {
    CREATED(EnumSet.of(Condition.A, Condition.B),
            EnumSet.of(Condition.C)),
    INSERTED(EnumSet.of(Condition.C),
             EnumSet.of(Condition.B),
    FAILED(EnumSet.noneOf(Condition.class),
           EnumSet.noneOf(Condition.class));

    private Set<Condition> successConditions;
    private Set<Condition> modificationConditions;

    RecordStatusEnum(Set<Condition> successConditions,
                     Set<Condition> modificationConditions) {
        this.successConditions = successConditions;
        this.modificationConditions = modificationConditions;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess(Condition c) {
        return successConditions.contains(c);
    }

    public boolean canBeModified(Condition c) {
        return modificationConditions.contains(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I need to have another check say canBeModified() which allows the following : 'INSERTED and B' , 'CREATED and C' ..?

Comment: Add another `Set<Condition> modificationConditions` to each enum. You'll have to change the constructor to take two `Set<Condition>` as argument, obviously. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is 'Condition' here? is it a class with properties 'status' and 'condition' which we should define? Shouldn't we define successConditions separately then? And why did you have the enums defined as CREATED (A, B) and INSERTED(C)?

Comment: I assumed the conditions were also designed as an enum (since you name them A, B, C, which looks like an enum to me). I also assumed the conditions for success and the conditions for modification were the same enum, but they could of couurse be two different enums (or Strings, or Integers, or whatever). What matters is the logic and the design. I defined them this way because that's how you defined them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also compare the ordinal values, like so:

```
public enum RecordStatusEnum {
   CREATED,
   INSERTED,   
   UPDATED,
   NEW,
   FAILED,
   FAILED_NO_DB,
   FAILED_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION;


 public boolean isPersisted(RecordStatusEnum status) {
    return status.ordinal < NEW.ordinal;
 }

 public boolean isError(RecordStatusEnum status){
    return status.ordinal >= FAILED.ordinal;
 }
```

}