# Validating a set of values retrieved from database

Tags: java, validation, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best approach for validating a combination of values using ENUMS in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788574/what-is-the-best-approach-for-validating-a-combination-of-values-using-enums-in)

I am getting two values from the database 'Value' and 'Check' which is being mapped to the enums ValueEnum ( A, B, C, D)  and CheckEnum (1, 2, 3) via Hibernate mapping.

These values needs to be validated such that I should allow different combinations for different checks.

For eg:

```
isChecked()  - should allow A1, A2, B3
isProcessed() - B2, C2, D3
```

These methods must be defined such that I would be able to add/remove conditions based on the requirement. Also must be defined externally, such that it is available to all my classes.

What is the best possible approach for this?

Comment: @JBNizet I did see that ques. but thought this is slightly diff. so wanted a diff view. n its not a homework. the values provided are not actual values, but they serve the purpose.